# Почему однокоренные слова пишутся по-разному?

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу разобраться, почему "приданое" пишется с одной -Н-, а "бесприданница" - с двумя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написание слова *приданое* и "*труженик*" действительно стоит запомнить. *Бесприданная* - та, которая без приданого. (От существительного на Н). То же и в слове   *бесприданница*.

Comment: Можно не запоминать, а, зная, что при переходе из одной части речи в другую слово обязательно получает суффикс, смело ставить два "н", ибо "приданое" - сущ., а "бесприданная" - прилагательное, а "бесприданница" образовалось, должно быть, от прилагательного.   
Труженик образовалось от существительного, то бишь перехода в другую часть речи не было.

Comment: Не во всем согласен с Вами, уважаемый коллега. 1.При переходе из одной части речи в другую не обязательно прибавляется второе "н" (например, мороженое). 2. Труженик, думаю, образовалось не от существительного, а от "труженый" (ср. натруженные руки),которое, в свою очередь, восходит к глаголу несовершенного вида "трудиться", отсюда и одна "н" в слове "труженик"

Answer (score 2):

В "бесприданнице" - "дан" - корень, "ница" суффикс. 
В "приданом" такого суффикса нет.

Можно конечно, залезть в исторические дебри и обосновать, что с диахронической точки зрения "н" в "дан" это тоже суффикс, но тогда он есть в обоих словах.

> Почему однокоренные слова пишутся по-разному?

Представления об однокоренных словах имеет очень мало отношения к вопросу правописания суффиксов.

Comment: Помнится, я здесь поднимала вопрос о странных опечатках вполне грамотных людей. Я их даже пыталась коллекционировать. Ваш "фопрос" так и просится в эту коллекцию!

Comment: Спасибо.
Это не "странная" опечатка. У неё есть медицинское название.
Кажется, я там об этом говорил.

Comment: Мне у нашего коллеги больше понравилось слово "залесзть"

Comment: Вот "залезсть" - это случайная опечатка. Во всяком случае напрямую с дисграфией не связана.

Comment: http://www.logoped.org/?key=disgrafia
(пункт № 2) 
Только в переложении на взрослый возраст.

Comment: Анонимным пользователем предложен следующая правка. Я к тому отношения не имею. Комментировать тут нечего, Сохраняю как память  ----------------------------------------------------------------

 В слове "приданое"  корень ДА, так как оно образовано от слова ДАть. В слове "бесприданница" две Н, потому что, согласно правилу, если слово образовано от основы, оканчивающейся на Н (ПРИДАНое), то к ней добавляется суффикс НИЦ. Слово "приданое" образуется от основы ПРИДАное с помощью суффикса Н.----------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Нашла на сайте [лицей](http://www.licey.net/russian/phonetics/3_8_3) такое правило:

**а) Н пишется в полных причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных:**

- если они не имеют приставок, зависимых слов, сочетания суффиксов -ованн-, -еванн- и если они образованы от глагола несовершенного вида;

  > Красить [что делать?] – крашеный пол; косить [что делать?] – кошеный луг, писать [что делать?] – писаный портрет.
- во фразеологизмах: посажёный отец, названый брат;
- в субстантивированном отглагольном прилагательном: приданое (невесты).

Меня смутило единственное число в последнем пункте. Получается, что приданое - это просто исключение? А например, *мороженое* - это тоже субстантивированное отглагольное прилагательное? Или субстантивирование здесь применено к чему-то другому?

Comment: Думаю, вы неправильно трактуете это единственное число. там не исключается других случаев.  
Мороженое - вполне себе субстантивированое и отглагольное. Но оно бесприставочное, тут вопросов нет.

Comment: Спасибо, успокоили. Видимо, просто авторы сайта неаккуратно выразились. Разница, пожалуй, только в том, что _приданое_ полностью субстантивировалось: вряд ли можно его использовать как прилагательное (мороженое мясо, приданое - что?)

Comment: Я думаю, это, типа, фигура речи. Вряд ли авторы вкладывали какой-то глубокий смысл в это единственное число.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, Ирина, за ссылку на "лицей". Я просмотрел весь параграф на интересующую тему и накнулся еще и на такую ремарку: "следует запомнить правописание существительных: труженик, приданое – бесприданница, ставленник". Правда, такая трактовка авторами сайта меня не очень устраивает. Слишком много предлагается запоминать, в том числе и те слова, правописание которых можно как-то объяснить. Например, -НН- в бесприданнице я объяснил бы тем, что это слово образовано от "бесприданная", где -НН- мотивируется наличием у исходного глагола "придать" приставки "при". Но почему тогда эта же приставка не позволяет "приданое" написать с -НН-?
Что касается "мороженого", то здесь все просто: от бесприставочного глагола "морозить" несовершенного вида, без пояснительных слов и других атрибутов, затем - субстантивация.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж не так далеко лезть, то можно вспомнить слово "дать", которое однокоренное к слову "приданое". Суффиксы "ть" и "а", следовательно, корень "д". 
Чтобы не ошибиться, проверил слово в [викисловаре](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/дать).

Comment: Валентин, вы когда-нибудь слышли что-нибудь о корневых чередованиях?
Если вы думаете, что корень это всегда общая часть однокоренных слов, то вы глубоко ошибаетесь. Если так думает ваша учительница, то можете ей передать то же самое и попросить её сделать морфемный разбор слова "вынуть". ;)

Comment: В этих двух словах нулевой корень.

Comment: В слове "дать" корень "да" и суффикс "ть"

Comment: Валентину - двойка, Виктору - три с минусом. )))

Виктор, а в слове "дань" где корень?

Comment: Нет, суффикс "а" - это словообразовательный суффикс, а "ть" - формообразовательный.

Comment: А что такое нулевой корень? И где он встречается? И как такое вообще возможно!?

Comment: Уважаемый...(не поворачивается язык употреблять Ваш ник, а имени Вашего не знаю)! В слове "дань" корень тот же - "да", а "нь" - это суффикс (от причастия "дан", в котором, согласно бессуффиксному способу словообразования, произошло смягчение "н". Подобное слово "пристань", похожее - "рань", хотя в последнем случае смягчилась последняя согласная корня.

Comment: wiktionary предлагает такой вариант:

- ***пристань*** - Приставка: при-; корень: -ст-.
- ***рань*** - Корень: -ран-; окончание: -ʲ.
- ***дань*** - Корень: --.

Если это неверно, то прошу там это поправить.

Comment: У нас уже не раз звучало, что википедия - это не академическое издание, которому можно безусловно доверять. С "пристань" согласиться можно, "рань" тоже логично, а вот "дань" не укладывается в рамки логики. "Дань"- это то, что дано (краткое причастие), от глагола "дать"

Comment: > У нас уже не раз звучало, что википедия - это не академическое издание, которому можно безусловно доверять

Ну, так кто будет делать, чтобы она была актуальная? Только своими силами!!!

Answer (score 0):

В слове "приданое"  корень ДА, так как оно образовано от слова ДАть. В слове "бесприданница" две Н, потому что, согласно правилу, если слово образовано от основы, оканчивающейся на Н (ПРИДАНое), то к ней добавляется суффикс НИЦ. Слово "приданое" образуется от основы ПРИДАть с помощью суффикса Н.

Comment: А кто-нибудь из серьезных авторов эту точку зрения разделяет?

Answer (score 0):

В слове "приданое" корень ДА, так как оно образовано от слова ДАть. В слове "бесприданница" две Н, потому что, согласно правилу, если слово образовано от основы, оканчивающейся на Н (ПРИДАНое), то к ней добавляется суффикс НИЦ. Слово "приданое" образуется от основы ПРИДАть с помощью суффикса Н.